# Call method after Logging .Net 5

Tags: c#, .net, logging, events

I have a .Net Worker program that uses multiple NuGet packages that log information to ILogger. For each of the NuGet packages, I am delegating same "master" logger object. For each of the log information, I would like to now fetch and send to our internal chat. I trying to create an Event that will execute a "CallMeWhenLog" method every time a new string is added to ILogger.

```
public class TestClass
{
   
    private readonly ILogger<TestClass> _logger;
    public TestClass(ILogger<TestClass> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Process(Message message, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
       _logger.LogInformation("New message!");
       _logger.LogError("New message!", ex);
    }
    
    public void CallMeWhenLog(string loggedMessage) 
    {
       var chatHandler = new ChatHandler();
       chatHandler.SendMessage(loggedMessage);
    }
}
```

I think it is possible by creating a subscription to ILogger but I never used events before. It sounds straight forward but I am a bit lost. For example, I would like to call "CallMeWhenLog" method just after _logger.LogInformation and _logger.LogError is executed.

Comment: Is the implementation of ILogger your own or 3rd party?

Comment: Is my own. I am initiating ILogger in default Program.cs as follow:

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
                {
                    logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                    logging.AddConsole();
                    logging.AddDebug();
                    logging.AddEventLog();
                })
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64913841/call-method-after-logging-net-5#comment114766978_64913841) it seems like you're using (ASP).NET Core.

You may want to look into creating your own Logger - [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#create-a-custom-logger), and registering it just like the other three logging provides (e.g. `logging.AddEventLog()`). You can implement posting to the chat in that custom logger.

Or take a look at the 3rd party providers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#third-party-logging-providers

Comment: Adding CustomLoggerProvider to ConfigureLogging did a job.